# Many-to-many relationship with non-zero cardinality

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, constraints

Let's say I have a PostgreSQL database with tables A, B and C, where A and B have a many-to-many relationship via junction table C. These tables have the following SQL definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE A
( 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT A_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE B
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT B_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE C
(
  A_id integer NOT NULL,
  B_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT C_pk PRIMARY KEY (A_id, B_id),
  CONSTRAINT A_fk FOREIGN KEY (A_id)
      REFERENCES A(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT B_fk FOREIGN KEY (B_id)
      REFERENCES B(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Now I want to make sure that there is at least one instance of B for each instance of A (in other words: each id in A occurs at least once as A_id in C). Is it possible to check this property using database constraints?

Comment: Have you tried to create a deffered foreign key from `A.id` to `C.A_id` ?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. But a foreign key is supposed to uniquely identify a row in another table. In this case there will often be more than one C.A_id that matches a A.id value, so it will not be unique. I am not sure whether this approach will maybe nevertheless still work, but it sounds a bit dirty to me.

Comment: The most generic solution would be to add a reference count to tables A and B; it would allow you to put _any_ limit on the number of references from the C table. But it would need trigger functions on the C table to maintain the counts in the A and B tables. BTW I don't think that a solution without triggers is possible. OTOH: is having _orphan_ rows in the {A,B} tables such a big problem, is there a logical reason to forbid them? (projects without workers, workers without projects seems fine to me, at least temporarily. Better than inventing dummy C rows to catch the idle ones)

Comment: @NiekTax Foreign key is just a constraint, that says: "for every in one table must exist same key in reference table". It does not imply one-to-many relation.

Comment: Any other check method (like a trigger) will have to do the same as a foreign key - check the reference table for an id. The difference - foreign keys will perform better, have less bugs and be easier to understand.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, the PSQL documentation states the following: "A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will be efficient." source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html.

Comment: @joop, thanks for the reference count/trigger solution. Indeed we need to have a proper internal discussion with the team on whether we actually need to use reference counts and triggers to prevent orphan rows, or whether we instead just decide to live with temporary orphan rows and do periodical clean ups.

Comment: This type of "at least N" inclusion dependency is almost impossible to maintain in declarative code in most SQL DBMSs. It's more or less a limitation of the SQL model that only one table can be updated at once. Common workarounds are to enforce the rule in procedural code (e.g. triggers), enforce it in an external rules engine or simply not to enforce it.

Comment: To add to @sqlvogel excellent comment, you can also create a background job, possibly via a stored procedure, that looks for violations to your rule, and notifies you when something is wrong. This isn't as good as real-time management but it would alert you to a code change that causes this problem inadvertently..

Comment: @sqlvogel and steve-midgley, thanks for your very valuable comments. A stored procedure approach indeed seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach for your requirement is a constraint trigger.

It should do an exists() check on table C and raise an exception when the required key doesn't exist. (Which, technically, is what the built-in triggers that enforce foreign key constraints basically do.)

It'll go something like:

```
create function A_C_fkey_check() returns trigger as $$
begin
  if not exists (select 1 from C where A_id = new.id) then
    raise exception 'invalid key';
  end if;
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create constraint trigger A_C_fkey_check after insert on A
for each row execute procedure A_C_fkey_check();
```

That said, I'd suggest that actually enforcing this type of constraint at the database-level isn't a great idea: bizarre edge cases that requires an A without a B invariably show up in my own experience.